# Using mongoimport with a single document containing a list of documents

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

Given the following document in a json file:

```
{
"session_date" : "03/03/2017",
"data" : [
{"user": "jack", "views": 10}
]
}
```

The JSON is valid if I copy it to the insert window of Robomongo, and results in inserting one document which contains a list of documents (a list of 1 document in this simple example).

Nevertheless, I am unable to do this with mongoimport:

```
> mongoimport --db mydb --jsonArray --collection mycollection --file data\test.json
> connected to: localhost
> Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array format - found no opening bracket '[' in input source
> imported 0 documents
```

Since it is a document and not an array of documents, I cannot use --jsonArray option.

Any help importing this?

Comment: (1) You can put this document as a single element of a list and then try. (2) Does it work if you remove `--jsonArray` from the args?

Comment: Bottom line is is should basically work simply by removing the `--jsonArray` option, unless there is something really different you are not showing here. At any rate, once imported you really need to attend to converting those `session_date` values to proper BSON Dates rather than strings. It's takes less storage, is useful for aggregation, and even as strings in the present format the order is not lexical and therefore cannot be queried for a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mongoimport --db mydb --collection mycollection --file data\test.json
```

should work for you if that's the [`simple import`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#simple-import) file you're planning to import anyway.

Just to add info, this shall create a document with the above JSON data in the `mycollection` under `mydb`.